# What function, f(x), converges to linear function when x -> inf as well as when x -> -inf

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence

I know that $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ does, but it is not good enough, because I need it to converge to $a+b x$ when $x\to\infty$ and $c+d x$ when $x\to-\infty$, with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$.

How to find the "simplest" or just some function with such properties?

Comment: I can't understand 'converge to $a+bx$ when $x\to\infty$'. $x$ should not be there.

Comment: @mathlove It means $f(x) - (a + bx) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @Arthur : Yes. That makes sense.

Comment: If you want to keep the style of $\sqrt{1+x^2}$, well, $y=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ has asymptotes $y=-x$ and $y=+x$ meeting at $(0,0)$. If $y=a+bx$ and $y=c+dx$ intersect, you can affine-transform the $xy$ plane to map $y=\pm x$ to them and obtain the corresponding transformation of $y=\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Comment: [The arctangent...?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find some function $f(x)$ that goes toward $0$ as $x \to -\infty$ and to $1$ as $x \to \infty$. Then you can make your function
$$
(ax + b)\cdot f(x) + (cx + d)\cdot f(-x)
$$
A small variation on either the error function or inverse tangent function gives relatively well-behaved $f$ (those are just suggestions off the top of my head), but you are free to make your own, like $\frac{e^x}{e^x + 1}$

Answer (score 0):

One of the examples is 
$$f(x)=2x+\sqrt{x^2-1}.$$

You'll know that 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \{f(x)-3x\}=0,$$
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \{f(x)-x\}=0.$$

This example is what you want because $f(x)$ converges to $0+3\cdot x$ when $x\to\infty$ and $f(x)$ converges to $0+1\cdot x$ when $x\to -\infty$. So, the $(a,b,c,d)=(0,3,0,1)$ case.

Answer (score 0):

Check this function

> $$ f(x) = a\, e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} + \sqrt{ 1+x^2 }. $$

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is a *simplest function* possessing two oblique asymptotes. Because this is precisely what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Try
$$f(x):={a+c+(b+d)x\over2}+{{\rm sgn}(b-d)\over 2}\ {\bigl|(a-c)+(b-d)x\bigr|\over2}\ .$$
If you want a smooth function you can replace the absolute value by $y\mapsto\sqrt{\epsilon^2+y^2}$ for some fixed $\epsilon$.